# Microsoft Vision API unable to process OCR

Tags: ocr

I am using the project from https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-vision-windows, I am able to upload image but the OCR is unable to be processed. It just stays on "Performing OCR..." Same for other functions except "Recognize Handwriting Text"

```
        //
        // Perform OCR on the given url
        //
        Log("Calling VisionServiceClient.RecognizeTextAsync()...");
        OcrResults ocrResult = await VisionServiceClient.RecognizeTextAsync(imageUrl, language);
        return ocrResult;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // KEY SAMPLE CODE ENDS HERE
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Perform the work for this scenario
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imageUri">The URI of the image to run against the scenario</param>
    /// <param name="upload">Upload the image to Project Oxford if [true]; submit the Uri as a remote url if [false];</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override async Task DoWork(Uri imageUri, bool upload)
    {
        _status.Text = "Performing OCR...";

        string languageCode = (languageComboBox.SelectedItem as RecognizeLanguage).ShortCode;

        //
        // Either upload an image, or supply a url
        //
        OcrResults ocrResult;
        if (upload)
        {
            ocrResult = await UploadAndRecognizeImage(imageUri.LocalPath, languageCode);
        }
        else
        {
            ocrResult = await RecognizeUrl(imageUri.AbsoluteUri, languageCode);
        }
        _status.Text = "OCR Done";

        //
        // Log analysis result in the log window
        //
        Log("");
        Log("OCR Result:");
        LogOcrResults(ocrResult);
    }
```

Comment: Please include your current code. Have you made any changes to the Github project? See this link for more details on how to create a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No i haven't made any changes to the Github project.